# Script to be executed on ssh connect

Tags: linux, ssh, scripting

There is a remote host, where I'd like to run a specific script every time I connect to it via ssh. Where should I put the file to be run automatically?

Answer (score 5):

From the ssh man page:

> ```
> ~/.ssh/rc
>          Commands in this file are executed by ssh
>          when the user logs in, just before the user's
>          shell (or command) is started.  See the
>          sshd(8) manual page for more information.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In the remote server?

ssh my-remote-host /usr/local/bin/my-remote-script

You can limit the ssh to run only one command with a specific key also, thus limiting the key usage. See http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/ for examples

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the authorized-keys file for the key you are connecting with (setup a private key auth as well) and use the command field in the file, for more info do a "man authorized-keys" to see what else you can setup.